# Which query is faster : top X or limit X when using order by in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

3 options, on a table of events that are inserted by a timestamp.

Which query is faster/better?

1. `Select         a,b,c,d,e.. from tab1 order by timestamp desc limit 100`
2. `Select top 100 a,b,c,d,e.. from tab1 order by timestamp desc`
3. `Select top 100 a,b,c,d,e.. from tab1 order by timestamp desc limit 100`

Answer (score 6):

When you ask a question like that, `EXPLAIN` syntax is helpful. Just add this keyword at the beginning of your query and you will see a query plan. In cases 1 and 2 the plans will be absolutely identical. These are variations of SQL syntax but the internal interpreter of SQL should produce the same query plan according to which requested operations will be performed physically.

More about `EXPLAIN` command here: [EXPLAIN in Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXPLAIN.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result by running these queries on a sample dataset. Here are my observations:

1. Type 1: 5.54s, 2.42s, 1.77s, 1.76s, 1.76s, 1.75s
2. Type 2: 5s, 1.77s, 1s, 1.75s, 2s, 1.75s
3. Type 3: Is an invalid SQL statement as you are using two LIMIT clauses

As you can observe, the results are the same for both the queries as both undergo internal optimization by the query engine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently both `TOP` and `LIMIT` do a similar job, so you shouldn't be worrying about which one to use.

More important is the design of your underlying table, especially if you are using `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses. In that case, you should be carefully choosing your `SORTKEY` and `DISTKEY`, which will have much more impact on the performance of Amazon Redshift that a simple syntactical difference like TOP/LIMIT.

Comment: Have to be careful about using with `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` as well. These can easily force the database to do a lot of work before returning just a few rows.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, using order by usually slow things down. and sure, I use timestmap as the sortkey in this case